# Implementing a PostProcessing manager

Tags: xna, post-processing

I have been thinking about how to implement a PostProcessing manager into my engine ([Vanquish](http://project-vanquish.co.cc)).

I am struggling to get my head around how a Post Processing technique works. I have read and viewed the Post Processing sample on the [creators.xna.com](http://creators.xna.com) webiste, but this seems to re-render the model applying the Post Processing effect.

I can add this functionality for static models, but when it comes to redrawing the Skinned Models, I then get confused as they already have their own techniques to their effects.

Can someone help me straighten my thoughts by pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Generally post-processing works over the entire screen. This is pretty simple, really.

What you do is set a render target on the device (I assume you can figure out how to create a render target from the sample):

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
```

From this point onward everything you render will be rendered to that render target. When you're done you can set the device back to drawing to the back buffer:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

And finally you can draw using your render target as if it were a texture ([this is new in XNA 4.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919060328/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx), in XNA 3.1 you had to call `GetTexture` on it).

So to making a post-processing effect:

- Render your scene to a render target
- Switch back to the back buffer
- Render your render target full screen (using `SpriteBatch` will do) with a pixel shader that will apply your post-processing effect.

You sound like you want to do this per model? Which seems kind of strange but certianly possible. Simply ensure your render target has a transparent alpha channel to begin with, and then draw it with alpha blending.

Or do you not mean post-processing at all? Do you actually wish to change the pixel shader the model is drawn with, while keeping the skinned model vertex shader?

Comment: This is great information.  I'm not wanting to do it on a per model basis, this is exactly what I am trying to get away from :o)